# Single word for "performed catastrophically badly" (in a computing context/sense)

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, slang, computing

I know I've heard this word but cannot place it. Help please?

I'm looking for the slang-like/tech jargon term one might read in a computer software developers' discussion or email exchange, if performance of something computer-related under development failed dreadfully (or was dismally/catastrophically poor) in a given case.

The usage is something like *"Testing went well, but output performance planked (or whatever the word is) when we added a second network card..."*

Comment: Do you mean "crashed"?  Usually reserved for complete failure -- the computer (or the program being discussed) ceasing to operate.  Or are you looking for "tanked" -- when some measure of performance dips precipitously.

Comment: "Borked" or "is borken"? (Slang, very superlative of "broken")

Comment: Tanked is the one. Borked will also do. I was almost there! Do you want to post them as an answers, since both are valid?

Comment: They aren't particularly professional but I've often heard devs using the terms SNAFU and FUBAR in these sorts of situations. Sidenote: we work with software that interacts with planes so the term "crash" is generally avoided.

Comment: @PhotoScientist - I'm guessing Tesla's folks try to avoid that term as well.

Comment: In the specific usage of the question, I'd likely say "Output performance was destroyed" or "Output performance imploded."

Comment: There are so many it seems to me - many types of negatives would work like "stunk" or "went to hell" or "disintegrated"  .. however "**cratered**"  is one that has a bit of an engineering flavor to it to my ear.  **imploded** is another one that has a bit of physics to it.

Comment: Tanked is used if the throughput goes way down.

Answer (score -2):

‘Coredumped’. Archaic, from UNIX crash report on TTY.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please consider adding a link to your source.

Comment: "Coredumped" is a term for an actual action computer systems can take, and is not appropriate in this context if a coredump didn't actually happen.

Comment: It can be used as slang, so it's entirely appropriate. Upvoting to offset.